# Bash - Output commands that can install listed npm global packages

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I know `npm ls -g --depth=0` will produce output

```
C:\Users\leon\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- create-react-app@1.5.2
+-- eslint@5.2.0
+-- prettier@1.13.7
`-- serve@9.4.0
```

I'm looking for a bash command that can output the following based on the above output:

```
npm i -g create-react-app
npm i -g eslint
npm i -g prettier
npm i -g serve
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slight refinement of the answer posted by @0.sh

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 |
sed -n 's/^[^A-Za-z0-9_]*//;s/@.*$//p' |
xargs -n 1 npm i -g
```

Moving the code into `xargs` causes the generated commands to be executed, not just printed. (If you don't want that, you can `xargs -n 1 echo npm i -g` to revert to just printing, or move the `npm i -g` back into the `sed` substitution.)

If you prefer, the extraction could be done with Awk or whatever instead. Even `grep`;

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 |
grep -o '[A-Za-z][^@]*' |
xargs -n 1 npm i -g
```

Notice also though that `npm ls` has options to generate `--parseable` or `--json` output formats, which is generally what you should use in scripts.

```
npm ls --global --parseable --depth=0 |
xargs -n 1 npm install --global
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `sed` tool to handle this

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 | sed -nE 's/^\W+/npm i -g /p'
```

Comment: It's really close, but how to produce them without the trailing `@version`

Comment: Add `s/@.*//;` just after the opening single quote.

Comment: `\W+` isn't properly portable, though; maybe switch to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]*` instead. Then you can also drop the `-E` option which isn't portable, either.

Comment: @tripleee can you post the full command plz, I'm not very familiar with bash syntax

Comment: I've done so now, and fixed a typo I noticed in this answer. +1